# How to write a bat. file that will change DNS settings to automatic?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, batch-file

We have a few clients who have to use a VPN connection to a warehousing network. the connection is done via a client portal, but when they log back out their DNS settings have had an additional DNS server Suffix.

This blocks the users from accessing any network drives on our domain, and the only way to restore these features is to manually go over and change the settings (the users are not IT literate, and networks settings are protected by an administrator password anyhow).

Is it possible to write a batch file that will change their DNS settings to automatic and remove and suffixes? this way we could leave the .bat on their desktop and tell them to simply click it when they have disconnected from the warehousing network.

Comment: What is the client os? Are they in a domain? Since the network settings are protected and take an admin, how were you planning gaining the appropriate rights ?

Comment: Client OS is windows 7, they're on our local domain. So I'm taking it there is no way to run an elevated cmd script by embedding admin credentials within the .bat itself? we're not particularly worried about security, as they users aren't computer literate so would know how to break apart and at the .bat script

Comment: Yes there are ways to do this depending on resources. Embedding admin level usernames / password would be something most groups would at least want a log of who and when every time it was used..

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to make a Group Policy that set the settings you wanted and have the user or bat file run a GPUpdate /force. This would not require messing with security settings or admin passwords for the users.

Comment: @bvaughn, perfect! what an elegant solution. thanks so much.

Comment: @bvaughn, hang on - Don't users have to log off/back on again to apply GPO updates? this wouldn't be very useful

Comment: depends on the gp, but no, a gpupdate /force can be used in loo of a reboot. If there was a GP that required a reboot such as a software install, then there is no way around.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional If you want to share you a vbscript that i made before to change the DNS to another like OpenDNs and it can also revoke this change ?